# Semantic UI Dropdown not working and says $(...).dropdown is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

This little task is causing a bigger headache than it needs. I just wanna get a simple dropdown like: [image]

Pretty easy, right? It even gives me the code? How hard could it be? I first imported the CDN in my page.

```
<head>
  <!-- stuff -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.css">
</head>
```

and then after all that, I add:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

According to their [documentation](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/usage), all I need to do is:

```
$('.ui.dropdown')
  .dropdown()
;
```

on my `ui-dropdown` class element, but it just gives me problems.

```
<Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dropdown is not a function
```

I looked at the following things to help, but didn't have much luck:

- [Semantic-UI Dropdown Not Working #229](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/229)
- [semantic-ui dropdown menu do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347315/semantic-ui-dropdown-menu-do-not-work)
  but didn't have luck
- Moving jQUery so it loads first
- Adding the *simple* class

It just looks like no matter what I do... the script isn't getting initialised.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your code to somewhere (jsfiddle or codesandbox) so we can detect the problem easier? (Sorry I don't have enough reputation to just comment on your question yet)

=======

**My answer:**

It seems that your code ran before the jQuery library being fully loaded to your browsers. Can you try wrap your execution codeblock into `$( document ).ready(function(){}` like this?

`$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('select').dropdown()
});`

Comment: Here's a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/dsomel21/pen/zReVEB), but this one works. I think this has something to do with the way I am rendering my layouts.

Comment: I have added my answer, please try. But I agree with @dsomel21, it's not semantic UI-related ;)

Answer (score 1):

This was **not** related to Semantic UI.

It was due to the way the DOM was being rendered. In my case, I had nested snippets (Rails Partials) and in seems like Semantic does not like when you initialize with `.dropdown()` in the child view.

Hence, I fixed this by initializing in parent and it works like a charm!

Comment: I am having the same issue now. Do you mind show some more details about how to `putting in the parent`? Does it refer to HTML structure?

Comment: Was the CodePen snippet helpful at all?