# semantic-ui drop down list is not working in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, html-select, semantic-ui

I am trying to implement [semantic-ui](https://semantic-ui.com) in **WordPress** with **Contact Form 7** plugin. I included semantic-ui css and js in head section. My inclusion is like below

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://127.0.0.1/sm/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=5.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='http://127.0.0.1/sm/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=5.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-block-library-css'  href='http://127.0.0.1/sm/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver=5.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-block-library-theme-css'  href='http://127.0.0.1/sm/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/theme.min.css?ver=5.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='contact-form-7-css'  href='http://127.0.0.1/sm/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=5.1.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentynineteen-style-css'  href='http://127.0.0.1/sm/wp-content/themes/twentynineteen/style.css?ver=1.4' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentynineteen-print-style-css'  href='http://127.0.0.1/sm/wp-content/themes/twentynineteen/print.css?ver=1.4' type='text/css' media='print' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='semantic_ui_style-css'  href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css?ver=5.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://127.0.0.1/sm/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://127.0.0.1/sm/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://127.0.0.1/sm/wp-content/themes/twentynineteen/js/school_management.js?ver=5.2.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js?ver=5.2.2'></script>
```

I read this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347315/semantic-ui-dropdown-menu-do-not-work) post. As per this post I added `$('.ui.dropdown')
  .dropdown();` this code as like below

[image]

But I am getting below output

[image]

How can I solve the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

If you initialize with `$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();`make sure your page references dropdown.js

Comment: Thanks @Imtiaz Ahmed. How can I references dropdown.js ? Thanks

Comment: in footer you can try with this- $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.ui.dropdown') .dropdown();
    });

Comment: @abuabu you need to enqueue your assets for admin panel.

**In function.php**

`function semantic_ui_assets($screen) {
if ( 'options-general.php' == $screen ) {
  wp_enqueue_script( "pqrc-minitoggle-js", plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . "/assets/js/dropdown.js", array( "jquery" ), "1.0", true );
 }
}
add_action( "admin_enqueue_scripts", "semantic_ui_assets" );`